# how to write filtered expressions in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to generate email alerts on the particular due date in Team Foundation Server(TFS)?? 
I am new to TFS.
Please reply in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The TFS Email Alert system is triggered by WorkItem changes, Builds and checkins  not date/times.  I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: Using the Power Tools by MS we can generate an e-mail when the due date is assigned.If that is possible.. I think generating the e-mail on the due-date may also be possible..

Comment: You can generate one when due date is assigned as that triggers a workitem change,  work items don't automatically change on their due date so no event is fired.

Comment: Hi Betty.. thanks for the reply.. now my question is that can we edit  the filtered expression in the back ground and generate the mail???

Comment: If this cannot be done.. pls get me another alternative solution to resolve this issue..

Comment: Write a custom application using the api, or write a SSRS Report from the cube that shows overdue items, which you can then use SSRS to subscribe to a daily email.